# Unable to have access to FTP to install a slider module, use external source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say my site is: example.com

I am unable to get access to edit css files and add additional files.

Lets say I install a module on exampleTWO.com...is it possible to use that site's slider for example.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can link to external resources. I've seen this done most commonly with JQuery, but the same rules apply to other resources. See this link here for more info: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

All you need to do is rather than have something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/sliderModule.js"></script>
```

You include the entire external address like so:

```
<script src="http://exampleTWO.com/js/sliderModule.js" ></script>
```

As far as CSS is concerned, I believe it will work the same way. I have never actually tested this though, so someone feel free to correct me if I am wrong in that assumption. If you cannot link to external CSS files, then simply include the CSS you'd like in the HTML between `<style>` tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you have any suggestions on some good third part slider code? Free or Paid.

Comment: @Smith That's up to you, just Google for them, there are tons out there.